# Select matched option with React Bootstrap Typeahead

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

In my React Bootstrap Typeahead component, the user can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select the currently matched option. How can I accept <kbd>Enter</kbd> as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `selectHintOnEnter` prop to achieve this behavior:

```
<Typeahead
  options={[ ... ]}
  selectHintOnEnter
/>
```

Enabling this prop will allow users to select the hint by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> as well as <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Here's a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-bootstrap-typeahead-select-on-enter-wctij).